# А чего модератор ответ удалил?

Tags: обсуждение

А чего модератор ответ удалил?
[Этимология слова "тысяча"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429557/%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум потому, что его неудобно читать и вообще ответы-изображения не приветствуются. Можно еще усомниться в академичности ответа.

https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic -- вот здесь чуть-чуть про изображения и вопросы (но ответов это тоже касается)